# scala reflection without typeOf

Tags: scala, reflection

How to call setter method through scala reflection api in the case where I don't use universe.typeOf[T] for getting members, but read class name from xml file.

I added example.

```
class Person

class Student(val name: String, val parent: Person){
   var node: String = _
}


<beans>
  <bean id="person" class="com.test.Person"/>

  <bean id="student" class="com.test.Student">
      <constructor signature="this(String,Person)">
        <arg value="Test name"/>
        <arg ref-val="person"/>
      </constructor>

      <property name="note" ref-val="Some note"/>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

This is how I get fields

```
val classMirror =  ru.runtimeMirror(getClass().getClassLoader())
    .classSymbol(Class.forName(className))
classMirror.asType.toType.members.filter {
  item =>       
    !item.isMethod && item.isTerm
}
```

Then I get setter from field

```
field.asMethod.setter
```

I am not shure how to call apply of setter if it possible at all. Also I am not shure did I get id in right way.

Comment: Just to understand you: You have a class with a setter method. The classname is unknown to you but found in an XML-file (?). You want to get the class and call the setter-method?

Comment: And are you looking for an existent instance of that class? Because you are mentioning a "setter". Or are we talking about a constructor here? :)

Comment: I have edited question.                                              Yes, I want to create object of that class and populate it. Yes, and setter(scala setter) and constructor. Your question about constructor give me idea maybe to try get fields from instance not from class.

Comment: Yes, if I first create instance and then reflect it I can get things work.

Answer (score 5):

I figure out it at the end, I had to create person object. If Person class has attribute name of type String this code will work:

```
val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val classSymbol = rm.classSymbol(Class.forName("com.bsi.workflow.test.Person"))
val classMirror = rm.reflectClass(classSymbol)

val constructorSymbol = classMirror.symbol.toType.members.find {
  item =>
     item.isMethod && item.asMethod.isConstructor
}

val person = classMirror.reflectConstructor(constructorSymbol.get.asMethod)()
val nameSymbol = classMirror.symbol.toType.members.find {
   item => item.name.decoded == "name"
}

val setter = nameSymbol.get.asMethod.setter.asMethod

val cr = rm.reflect(person)

cr.reflectMethod(setter).apply("hi")

println(person.asInstanceOf[Person].name)
```